# Ho to check if <td> inner text is less than 5 and applied a class in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a class only on tds which have text value less than 5. issue is class is applying on all tds.

```
var table = $("table tbody");
table.find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
  var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
      lessNumber = $tds.eq(0).text();
  newNumber = $tds.eq(0).text() > 5;
  if(lessNumber < 5){
    $tds.addClass("danger-color")
  }

});
```

Comment: I think your problem is that `$tds.eq(0).text()` is not a number so when you do `$tds.eq(0).text() > 5` it says `string > number` so try add a `+` before `+$tds.eq(0).text() > 5` the + converts it to a number

Comment: note that while `("4"<5)===true` equally `("45"<5)===true` so worth converting to number to be sure (there are various means, my preference is  `...text() * 1`)

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do: 1) apply the class on *every* cell that is `<5` or 2) apply the cell to the row when the first cell in that row is `<5` or 3) apply only to the first "column"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been useful to have had HTML

This will set the class of the first cell in each row if the cell contains  a numeric value less than 5.

Note the + that casts to number

```js
$("table tbody tr td:first-child").each(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("danger-color",+$(this).text()<5)
});
```

```css
.danger-color { color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  
  </tbody>
</table>
```